# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply') NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm relatively new to node and I have read through answers to this error without much success.
I'm building a multiplayer game using socket.io and serving the react app statically using express. The app displays the lobby successifully but the server throws this error as soon as the game starts.
Here is  the api

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const api = express.Router()

api.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public")))

module.exports = api
```

and server.js

```
const http = require('http')
const io = require('socket.io')

const sockets = require('./sockets')

const apiServer = require('./api')
const httpServer = http.createServer(apiServer)
const socketServer = io(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
})


const PORT = 4000

httpServer.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`)
})

sockets.listen(socketServer)
```

is there something I'm doing wrongly?

This are logs when the server start and connect two users

```
    Server is running on port: 4000
    User connected CTmTWswPSNdfhhl2AAAB
    {
      playerData: {
        pid: '53f7bfaf-bbbb-496c-a666-f55a9d574054',
        avatar: 11,
        name: 'Nyah'
      },
      players: 1
    }
    User connected UkfcIX202fDXJ6caAAAD
    {
      playerData: {
        pid: '09b68067-cc0d-460d-b28c-21cde0c54862',
        avatar: 9,
        name: 'Walter'
      },
      players: 2
    }
```

Then as soon as game starts:

```
    Game on Guys!!!
    /home/aimkeys/Development/projects/card-games/poker-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:646
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
                  ^

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
        at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/aimkeys/Development/projects/card-games/poker-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:646:15)
        at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:468:21)
```

The app is working correctly when I have started the frontend and the backend at different ports.

Comment: You cannot pass `api = express.Router()` as an argument to `http.createServer`. Use `api = express()` instead.

Comment: Day saved. Thank you very much!!